# TODO items show up multiple times in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, todo

The Task List in Visual Studio 2008 is behaving a little wacky for me. Some tasks are only shown once, but some are shown several times.

For example, `// TODO: Change this to 9000.0 when...` appears only once in my code (AcceptanceTests.cpp line 74), but it is showing up four times in the task list.

[image: ScreenshotOfVisualStudioTaskListWithDuplicates]

It seems that when the file is edited, an instance of the TODO with the correct line number is created but the old outdated instance is not removed.

Is there a way to refresh the task list?

I've tried rebuilding the solution, but it didn't help. And I'm not surprised because this has nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: Who comments their code with double-backslashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing and re-opening Visual Studio worked! No more duplicates (for now).

[image: screenshot showing problem fixed]